# Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

Unable to figure out what is causing the issue.

**My application.properties file**

```
    spring.datasource.url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Medical_Tracking?useSSL=false"
    spring.datasource.username=root
    spring.datasource.password=root
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Quick help is appreciated

Comment: What is your error stack trace? Please add that in your qstn

Answer (score 6):

Your config `spring.datasource.url` should not use double quotes (`"`)

instead of:

```
spring.datasource.url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Medical_Tracking?useSSL=false"
```

use:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Medical_Tracking?useSSL=false
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also get this error in case you are using wrong value for any of the datasource setting.

I was using driver class name in place of url

```
@Bean
@BatchDataSource
public DataSource batchDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().url(batchDbDriver)
            .driverClassName(batchDbDriver).username(batchDbUsername)
            .password(batchDbPassword)
            .build();
}



@Bean
@BatchDataSource
public DataSource batchDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().url(batchDbUrl)
            .driverClassName(batchDbDriver).username(batchDbUsername)
            .password(batchDbPassword)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following change in applications.properties file:

Replace

```
 spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

with

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: See this: https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/28/property-binding-in-spring-boot-2-0

Comment: I hope you understand that the reason you mentioned is not correct. The property can be defined in kebab case

Comment: yes I do and thank you! 
Actually, once I did follow this https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/datasource-configuration/ 
and it suggests to define this property differently for H2, MySQL, Oracle & SQL Server.
and for SQL Server, it suggests the same as I mentioned here! so I got confused with my old readings and MySQL & SQL Server!